# Spring batch - oracle connection closed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am facing a weird issue in my spring boot application and searched a lot but no luck for the answer. Basically, I have configured a very simple spring batch job with reader, processor and writer and I also have own data source configuration.

I have only one job configured and there are will be multiple invocations of this same job with different parameters. That is, same job url will be triggered with (10) different inputs at the same time and everything would be running in parallel. Every jobStep has a throttle of 4 threads and hence all 10 job instances will span 4 giving rise to 40 threads in parallel.

There are two problems I am encountering with this approach on daily basis and couldn't figure out the issue,

1. Once the application starts and when the jobs are triggered for first time, all 10 job instances (with different inputs) are getting completed successfully. No issues with that. But then, after 10 hours, if we try to trigger same job instance with another 10 inputs at the same time, all the jobs are getting failed with the below reason.

> o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher : Job: [FlowJob:
>   [name=marketing-job]] completed with the following parameters:
>   [{time=1513023822300, jobInput="CustomerA"] and the following status:
>   [FAILED] 
>   o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep : Encountered an error
>   executing step jobStep in job marketing-job
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 17008, SQLState:
>   08003 o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : Closed Connection

It just errors with connection closed. I have set testOnBorrow which should kind of ensure the pool connections are valid for the job, but that doesnt seem to work. Tried with testOnIdle as well but no luck...

2. Sometimes, even during the first run, obtaining the DB connection in reader is getting stuck for about 10-15 mins before it actually gets a connection. No clue on why is this happening.

Have anyone faced these issues ? Could anyone help me in getting this resolved please?

Have given the configurations for job and datasource below.

**JOBConfig:**

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration implements BatchConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

  @Autowired
  public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  @Autowired
  Reader reader;

  @Autowired
  Processor processor;

  @Autowired
  Writer writer;

  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSourcePrimary;

  @Autowired
  private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

  @Bean
  public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("marketing-job").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(jobStep()).end()
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step jobStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("jobStep")
        .<Object, Object>chunk(1).reader(reader)
        .processor(processor).writer(writer).taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
        .throttleLimit(4).build();
  }

  @Override
  public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
    return jobLauncher;
  }

  @Bean
  public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(100);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(120);
    return taskExecutor;
  }

  @Override
  public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {

    JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(oracleTransactionManager);
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSourcePrimary);
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
  }

  @Override
  public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
    return transactionManager;
  }

  @Override
  public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
    return null;
  }
}
```

**DataSourceConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryPrimary",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
    basePackages = "com.sample")
public class DatasourceConfig {

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "dataSourcePrimary", destroyMethod = "")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

      dataSource.setInitialSize(50);
      dataSource.setMaxIdle(50);
      dataSource.setMaxTotal(60);
      dataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1 from dual");
      dataSource.setValidationQueryTimeout(10);
      dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
      dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
      //dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(600000);
      //dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(600000);

    return dataSource;

  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryPrimary")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSourcePrimary") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.sample.entity")
        .persistenceUnit("primary").build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
      @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryPrimary") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryPrimary) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryPrimary);
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerPrimary")
  public EntityManager entityManager(
      @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryPrimary") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryPrimary) {
    return entityManagerFactoryPrimary.createEntityManager();
  }
}
```

**Update: Added Reader & Writer as per the request**

```
@Component
@StepScope
@RefreshScope
public class Reader
    implements ItemReader<A>, StepExecutionListener {

  private List<A> a;

  @Override
  public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    List<A> aList =
        new ArrayList<A>();
     // code to populate the data list 'a' from DB.
  }

  @Override
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized A read() {
    if (a.size() > 0) {
      return a.remove(0);
    }
    return null;
  }

}


@Component
public class Writer implements ItemWriter<A> {

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends A> a) {

    // get 'a' and write 
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm not confortable with Java-config but did you try removing  `@EnableTransactionManagement`? Maybe this annotations interfers with SB tx management

Comment: Can we see the configuration for your `ItemReader` and `ItemWriter`?  I'm wondering if there is some left over state between the runs...

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci : Thanks for the comment. Tried but no luck.

Comment: @MichaelMinella : Thanks for the reply. I added the reader and writer. Its a simple flow and not sure why connection is a problem here.

Comment: Your reader and writers don't access the db?

Comment: reader access db in beforeStep. Data list is populated in beforeStep and then fetched in the synchronized read() method.

Comment: @MichaelMinella: also db access is  by spring jpa. I do have a native query as well as a named query which will be triggered from the reader. We form the native query from entityManger.createNativeQuery("query"); I hope that's not an issue. Even today, batch jobs completed once and then the next trigger failed with connection closed issue.

Comment: We really need you to share the full code to be helpful...

Comment: sorry, am afraid I cant share the code. but i did found a clue that its not related to spring batch alone but with spring itself. I deviated from spring batch implementation by not launching the jobs rather running reader first ,processor and writer through a custom ThreadPool. The first run happens fine, but the consecutive runs still fail with connection closed.